# Prove big O notation for $\log(n!)$ without applying Stirling's formula

Tags: big-o-notation, factorial

I want to prove that,
$$ \log n! \in O(n \log n) \land \log n! \in \Omega(n \log n)$$
The straightforward approach is to apply Stirling's formula but I am looking for a different path to follow.

Can somebody please guide me towards it?

Comment: Using the convenient search box on top of this page, I found some earlier questions that might be relevant:
[Is log n! = Θ(n log n)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48358/4287),
[Is log(n!) in Θ(nlog(n))?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57457/4287), 
[Confused about proof that log(n!)=Θ(nlogn)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/47561/4287).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice method is :
$$ 
\begin{align*}
\log n! & = \log \prod_{\psi=1}^n \psi \\
& = \sum_{\psi=1}^n \log \psi \\
& \sim \int_1^n \log \psi \; \mathrm d \psi \\
& = \psi \log \psi - \psi \Biggr|_{1}^{n} \\
& = n \log n - (n - 1) 
\end{align*}
$$
If we had used stirling's approximation instead, we would have received
$$
\log n! = n \log n - n + \Theta(\log n)
$$
Alternate methods involve

- The method present in [this math.se page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870099/prove-that-logn-thetan-log-n-without-appealing-to-stirlings-formula).
- Using $n! = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} \; \mathrm d x$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your use of $\psi$ is intimidating.

Comment: The step from the sum to the integral needs to be justified. Because it could turn out that the "quantization error" modifies the asymptotic behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\log n! = \sum_{k = 1}^n \log k$. Then
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \log k = \int_1^{n + 1} \log \lfloor x \rfloor dx \le \int_1^{n + 1} \log x dx = (n + 1) \log (n + 1) - n,$$
and
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \log k = \int_0^{n} \log \lceil x \rceil dx \ge \int_0^{n} \log x dx = n \log n - n .$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, my problem has been solved

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, the solutions have all used integration. We can easily do without.
Of course $\log n! = \sum_{k=1}^n \log k$.

For the upper bound use $\log k \le \log n$ for $1\le k \le n$, so $\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \le \sum_{k=1}^n \log n =n \log n$.

For the lower bound, observe that $\log \frac n2 \ge \frac 12{\log n}$ for $n\ge 4$. Thus $\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \ge \sum_{k={\frac n2}}^{n} \log k \ge \frac n2 \log \frac n2 \ge \frac n4 \log n$.

Comment: This simple "trick" of lower bounding a sum by only some of its terms (usually half, not always) is enough to give the asymptotic behaviour (up to a constant factor) of most sums one might encounter in beginner algorithms courses.

Answer (score 1):

For complete rigor,

$$x-1\le\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$

so that by monotonicity of the logartihm

$$\log(x-1)\le\log\lfloor x\rfloor\le \log x.$$

Hence by integration from $2$ to $n+1$,

$$\int_1^n\log x\,dx\le\sum_{k=2}^n\log k\le\int_2^{n+1}\log x\,dx$$

and

$$n\log n-n+1\le\log n!\le(n+1)\log(n+1)-n+1-2\log2.$$

Answer (score -1):

Without any hard maths: log n! = log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + … + log n. We are adding n numbers, each at most log n, so the sum is at most n log n.

On the other hand, log ( sqrt (n)) = (log n) / 2, so all but sqrt(n) of the numbers we are adding are at least (log n) / 2, giving a lower bound. For n>= 4, sqrt(n) <= n/2 so we are adding at least n/2 numbers, each at least (log n) / 2, for a total of (n log n) / 4.